# error for missing bracket without apparent reason

Tags: linux

I'm writing a bash function to verify if a given input file is readable, regular and not a symbolic link however i am getting a missing bracket error.

```
function vfile(){
local infile=$1;
if [ ! $1 ]; then
        getname;
else
        getname $1;
fi;
if [ $? == 1 ]; then
        return;
else
infile=$fname;
fi;
if [ -f $infile && -r $infile ];
then
        if [ ! -h $infile ];
        then
                echo "$infile";
                (exit 0)
                return;
        else
                echo "$infile";
                (exit 1)
                return;
        fi;
else
        (exit 2)
        return;
fi
}
```

I am getting the error on line 37 which is strange to me because the if statement has proper spacing which seems to cause these errors, so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` is not supported inside of `[...]`.  Replace:

```
if [ -f $infile && -r $infile ]
```

With:

```
if [ -f "$infile" ] && [ -r "$infile" ]
```

Also note that your variables should be inside double-quotes to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.

#### Aside

For better compatibility, replace:

```
function vfile(){
```

with

```
vfile(){
```

This new form will work in all POSIX shells.  The `function` keyword is bash-specific and adds no value.